# Load Balancer for a C# Console application

Tags: c#, windows, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I have a C# console application which uses socket connections and it is deployed on a EC2 Windows machine. I need to configure AWS Load Balancer to it so that traffic is equally distributed among multiple Windows machines. What port should we configure load balancer to in case of a console application?

Comment: Yes, I am configuring a Network Load balancer, but I need to specify a port for that too.

Comment: Surely you know what port your application is listening on? I imagine you need to provide a port for NLB to expose your application to the Internet on, and also provide the port number that your application listens on so that NLB is able to route to it.

Comment: I am a newbie to working with console applications (I have been working more with web applications till now). Is there a default port that console applications listen to or is it something we configure? How can I check that?

Comment: _"Is there a default port that console applications listen to"_ - if you wrote a console application that listens on a TCP/IP port, then it's that port. If you didn't specify one, then it's a random free port each time you launch the application.

Comment: Got the port the application was running on (using netstat) and configured this on AWS Network Load Balancer, security groups configured to be allowed for inbound on this port, windows inbound firewall is also allowed for this port. However NLB Health check fails.